# Magento2 blank white screen after clicking on custom menu item

Tags: magento2, frontend, page-layouts, custom-menu

When I print anything from controller it works, but when i try to add .phtml with this code, blank screen appears

> app/code/Company/Configuration/view/adminhtml/layout/configuration_admin_settings.xml-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Greetings
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Company_configuration::masterSettings.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and phtml file inside

> app/code/Company/Configuration/view/adminhtml/templates/masterSettings.phtml-

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: any error in log file?

Answer (score 0):

can you change this code:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Company_Configuration::masterSettings.phtml"/>
```